# Is it possible to construct a non constant kernel between two identical numbers?

Tags: kernel-trick, gaussian-process

Consider the kernel methods in machine learning that are used in Support Vector Machine, Gaussian Process, etc. We need to define $k(x;y)$ that measures the similarity between two data points $x;y$. The common choice is the radial basis function [RBF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_kernel) kernel:
$k(x;y)=exp(- || x-y ||^2)$ .

In most of the cases, $k(x;x)$ is constant and does not depend on $x$. I am wondering if there is any kernel function such that $k(x;x)$ is dependent on $x$. If there is, how is it called? Any reference is helpful.

Answer (score 5):

One easy example is the linear kernel $k(x, y) = x^T y$, so that $k(x, x) = \lVert x \rVert^2$, or the polynomial kernel $k(x, y) = (x^T y + c)^d$.

In general, this kind of kernel is known as *nonstationary*: its values vary over the input space. There are an infinite number of them, but I'm not aware of any in common usage other than the two I just listed.

There's an interesting subclass of these kernels discussed by:

> Genton (2001). *Classes of Kernels for Machine Learning: A Statistics Perspective*. Journal of Machine Learning Research 2 299–312. ([official pdf](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume2/genton01a/genton01a.pdf))

locally stationary kernels, originated perhaps by Silverman, of the form
$$
K(x, y) = K_1\left( \frac{x + y}{2} \right) K_2\left( x - y \right)
,$$
so that the normal stationary kernel $K_2$ is scaled by a function of the average location $K_1$.

The following paper I haven't read discusses some other options:

> Paciorek and Schervish. *Nonstationary Covariance Functions for Gaussian Process Regression.* NIPS 2004. ([official pdf](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/2350-nonstationary-covariance-functions-for-gaussian-process-regression.pdf))

Comment: Hi @Dougal, I asked a question [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253333/reducible-nonstationary-kernels) about the Genton paper you cited.  I would like to hear your opinion on it if you have some time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not a real kernel but the [sigmoid kernel](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90736/the-difference-of-kernels-in-svm) has this behavior. It's the hyperbolic tangent of the dot product of two numbers combined with a slope term and a constant term.  From the link: $K(X, Y) = \tanh(γ\cdot X^TY + r)$