# Is it possible to yield high-dimensional data from its low-dimensional point in KPCA?

Tags: pca, kernel-trick, high-dimensional

With PCA, it is possible to reconstruct high-dimensional data from its low-dimensional point by
$$
x_i' = Pb + \bar X
$$
Where $\bar X$ is the mean of training set $X$, $P$ is the eigenvectors and $b$ is a principal component.

Can this be achieved with kernel PCA (KPCA)? If so, how?

Comment: +1. See my answer here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131142, in particular around the reference to the Mika et al. 1998 paper. They call it "pre-image". You can also try googling `pre-image kernel PCA` (try this [google scholar query](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=pre-image+kernel+pca)) and browse through the literature. I am not particularly familiar with it.